# How to remove cookie by name in package react-native-cookie

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I set a cookie by name and I want to remove that particular cookie not all cookies in react-native-cookie package for react native app.

Comment: They have an instance method of CookieManager `CookieManager.clearByName('cookie_name')` documented in their repo for IOS only.

Comment: I need to clear cookie for both ios and android.

Comment: @AkhilAmarneni did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having to clear a cookie by name on my android device. IOS works fine.